# Why am I getting ERR 1 on my 80D when I shoot with a small aperture?

Tags: lens, aperture, error, canon-80d

Whenever I try to take a picture with a small aperture, say f/13, the camera won't shoot and displays "Err 1: Faulty Lens Communication, Clean Lens contacts" and upon doing so, it won't change a thing.

Camera: Canon 80D
Lens: 18-55mm IS (pretty old)

Though the lens is old and cheap, I haven't encountered any such problem until going to a place where the temperature reached -5°C, and I still don't see any obvious signs of deterioration.  But this is now happening even when the camera is warmed up to room temperature and leaving it to dry a bit doesn't work.

Comment: just to clear out your edit: this is happening now at room temperature, too?

Comment: Yes. Even warming it up in room temp. and leaving it to dry a bit doesn't work.

Comment: To me, it sounds like there is some moisture inside the blades of the aperture which slows it down - and so, the lens perhaps won't report ready in the time frame where the 80D would expect it. Note: This is a wild guess. Perhaps you can see it misbehave when adjusting to the highest aperture and pressing the depth of field preview-button and looking into the lens?

Comment: Hmmm, the only problem now seems to be the aperture. When the aperture is too small, it wont shoot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the temperature extreme may have affected the aperture mechanism in your lens or the lens side of the communication path between the camera and the aperture mechanism.

It might be something as simple as a lubricant freezing and crystallising in a way that it no longer has the same properties after warming back up. It could be something as catastrophic as moisture inside the lens expanding as it froze and causing a continuity issue on a printed circuit board inside the lens.

In practical terms there's not much difference regardless of the cause: just having someone open the lens up to look at it is probably going to cost more than the lens is worth. You can try more passive 'repair' methods such as keeping the lens warm and dry for several days and see if that helps. Otherwise I'm afraid it is probably time to consider another lens or you can continue using the lens in away that works around the fault.

The original non-IS versions of the EF-S 18-55mm kit lenses were not that good. The IS versions are better, but they are still on the lower end of optical performance compared to most of the lenses available for your Canon EOS camera. The 80D is a very capable camera. You can take this opportunity to put a lens on it that will allow you and your camera to more fully reach your potential.